# jQuery .post gives error in Chrome, not IE

Tags: jquery

I am performing a very simple post operation that behaves differently in IE and Chrome.

```
// using jquery-1.8.0.min.js

// URL for post
var collectionurl2 = "/DBView/DBView/UntypedCollection"; 

// serialized form elements
var formelements = { 
  serializedformdata: JSON.stringify($('#form2').serializeArray()) 
};
$.post(collectionurl2, formelements, function (data) {
  alert("Success");
}, "json")
.error(function () {
  alert("Error! Failed posting to " + collectionurl2);
});
```

In Chrome I get error alert, whereas in IE I get success. I have confirmed multiple times that cache is cleared. When I set a breakpoint in the controller I see that in Chrome the error triggers BEFORE the controller is activated, so the error seems to be something related to post attempt and nothing to do with any response activity. I am unsure how best to proceed and would appreciate suggestions on how to debug/troubleshoot.

Comment: What's the error? Can you remove the `.error()` callback and check your console for an error message?

Comment: Try to simplify your data format : ´var formelements =  $('#form2').serialize();´

Comment: I believe your event is triggering on submit button. Change it to normal input button.

Comment: sdespont, understand your point but I intentionally create the data format per a controller binding approach in .NET - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539966/posting-json-to-mvc-controller-string-parameter-is-null

Comment: Kundan, I use a jQuery .click event as trigger: $('#search2').click(function (event) { // OP info in here  });

Answer (score 0):

Kundan's mention of submit trigger led me to look at default submit behavior. I was already using a normal button as he proposed, but I nee