# How would I deserialize the string created below with ServiceStack.Text?

Tags: json.net, servicestack

Hi I am trying to use the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539966/posting-json-to-mvc-controller-string-parameter-is-null/12540097#12540097)
by using ServiceStack.Text to deserialize but I haven't been able to figure out the correct way to do this. Currently trying to do this in DotNet 3.5.

I am willing to consider answers using JSON.Net as long as I can do it in dotnet 3.5.

```
var formelements = { serializedformdata: JSON.stringify($('#form').serializeArray()) };
```